# Android Target API version 33.0 Xamarian.Firebase.Messaging is not working

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-2010, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I am running an application on .NET 6 with Xamarian MAUI and can see that Xamarian.Firebase.Messaging latest version is not compatible with this. I am not sure what I can do to make it compatible with API version 33.0. Please help

I was having 31 as the target version and added Xamarian.Firebase.Messaging nuget package in my project but after specifying the target version of android to 33.0 the Xamarian.Firebase.Messaging package is showing a warning and while debug it gives a runtime build error.

Comment: You can follow up this issue: [Dotnet 7 Support - Will that be coming?](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/806#issuecomment-1754264317).